# How to connect to already running go ethereum client using mist Ubuntu

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Mist tries to use its own go-ethereum client instead of using already running client and produces binding address error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by using

```
sudo mist --rpc="path to the private chain ipc"
```